# map two payload data based on commom field and country

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

I have payload from which I need to extract only list of `creator_by__v` fields as list of strings from payload OBJECTS where `abbreviation__c=='CN'`. The payload is below.

The payload is:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "created_by__v": 2447129,
            "document_country__vr": {
                "responseDetails": {
                    "limit": 250
                },
                "data": [{
                    "name__v": "China",
                    "abbreviation__c": "CN"
                }]
            },
            "version_modified_date__v": "2020-11-30T06:33:41.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zanb.png)

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` to get only the entries you need and then map to extra the `created_by__v` values

```
(payload.data filter $.document_country__vr.data[0].abbreviation__c == "CN") 
  map $.created_by__v as String
```

[image]

Comment: hi, I'm getting an empty array as output using the above data weave code

Comment: Hi. I did a small modification in the script (data is an array, so I'm selecting the first element and equals was wrong) and added an image of how it looks now. Check if the input is similar to the one I'm using.

Comment: hi thanks i will check it, also there are multiple objects inside the first data array, so we will get multiple created_by__v values  , and also we need to get the unique values of created_by__v for abbreviation__c=='CN'

Comment: You can use `distinctBy` to get unique values https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-distinctby

Comment: Hi jorge i have this but still not able to get output as required? can you please help me?

Comment: Hi Bala. Can you improve the original question with and input and the expected output including all the cases you need to cover (repetitions, uniques, etc)?